# Return false no funciona dentro de un each

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy recorriendo una tabla con datos , presionar buscar toma el valor del input y lo busca en la tabla , cuando lo encuentra necesito que corte la ejecución de la función que es lo que no consigo realizar gracias.

```js
function BuscarCodigo() {
  $("#table tbody tr").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text() == $('#codigo').val()) {
      alert("codigo ya ingresado");
      return false;//no funciona , no detiene la ejecucion de la funcion
    }
  });
  //estos alerts no deberian mostrarse por que necesito detener la ejecucion en el "return false" 
  alert("llego");//aca no deberia llegar 
  alert("llego");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="codigo" type="text"> 
<button type="button" onclick="BuscarCodigo()"> Buscar</button>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>4859</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>2568</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Estás seguro que entra? ya limpiaste la caché del navegador?

Comment: ocurre exactamente lo realizado en el ejemplo al usar return false, no detiene la ejecución de la función.

Comment: el `return false` está saliendo del `each` más no de la función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el return es para el foreach no para la función, lo que hace ahí es que ya no sigue iterando pero sigue la función, podrías intentar algo así

```js
function BuscarCodigo() {
  var fin = false;
  $("#table tbody tr").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text() == $('#codigo').val()) {
      alert("codigo ya ingresado");
      fin = true;
      return false;//no funciona , no detiene la ejecucion de la funcion
    }
  });
  //estos alerts no deberian mostrarse por que necesito detener la ejecucion en el "return false" 
  if(fin) {
   return false;
  }
  alert("llego");//aca no deberia llegar 
  alert("llego");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="codigo" type="text"> 
<button type="button" onclick="BuscarCodigo()"> Buscar</button>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>4859</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>2568</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: justo lo que necesitaba gracias !

Answer (score 2):

Sí funciona , de hecho es la forma correcta de salir de un `each` ,pero no de una función. al hacer `return false` no está cortando la ejecución de la función si no del método `each` , se podría comprobar haciendo un `console.log` a la fila iterada y si buscas el primer valor , solo mostrará este y no el segundo. Para salir de la función podrías tener una `bandera` *(seencontro)*. y al final de la función solo retorna dicha bandera que tendrá el estado de la búsqueda.

```js
function BuscarCodigo() {
  var seencontro = false;
  $("#table tbody tr").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text() == $('#codigo').val()) {
      // Para verificar que si se corta el each
      console.log($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text());
      alert("codigo ya ingresado");
      seencontro =true;// si se encontró el valor , seteamos la bandera a true
      return false;//si funciona detiene la ejecución del each
    }
  });
  // retornamos la bandera.
  return seencontro;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="codigo" type="text"> 
<button type="button" onclick="BuscarCodigo()"> Buscar</button>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>4859</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>2568</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es el equivalente a la función [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some). El problema es que jQuery no trae dicha función, pero puedes añadirla así:

```
jQuery.fn.some = function(fn, thisArg) {
  var result;

  for (var i=0, iLen = this.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

      if (typeof thisArg == 'undefined') {
        result = fn(this[i], i, this);

      } else {
        result = fn.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
      }

      if (result) return true;
    }  
  }
  return false;
}
```

Con lo que tu código quedaría algo así:

```js
jQuery.fn.some = function(fn, thisArg) {
  var result;

  for (var i=0, iLen = this.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

      if (typeof thisArg == 'undefined') {
        result = fn(this[i], i, this);

      } else {
        result = fn.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
      }

      if (result) return true;
    }  
  }
  return false;
}

function BuscarCodigo() {
  var fin = $("#table tbody tr").some(function(el) {
    if ($(el).text().lastIndexOf($('#codigo').val())!=-1) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  if(fin) {
    alert("codigo ya ingresado");
    return false;
  }
 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="codigo" type="text"> 
<button type="button" onclick="BuscarCodigo()"> Buscar</button>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>4859</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>2568</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```